# Eliminating function call wrappers

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have a free function which takes a couple of arguments:

```cpp
T frobnicate(int x, int y, int z) {
  // …
}
```

And then I have a wrapper for it, which basically holds one of the arguments:

```cpp
class A {
 public:
  T frobnicate(int y, int z) {
    return frobnicate(x, y, z);
  }
 private:
  int x;
};
```

And another wrapper class, which holds another argument.

```cpp
class B {
 public:
  T frobnicate(int z) {
    return a.frobnicate(y, z);
  }
 private:
  A a;
  int y;
};
```

And then we call it (with all fields appropriately initialized somewhere) in another place.

```cpp
void main() {
  B b;
  int z;
  T result = b.frobnicate(z);
}
```

This has direct disadvantages for me:

- All the functions have the same name. This somewhat makes sense because they all have the same effect and only differ in arguments. Yet they aren't interchangeable or parallel implementations of the same thing like `std::abs(int)` and `std::abs(double)` or things like `std::sort(begin, end)` and `std::sort(begin, end, compare)`. Coming up with good names is difficult, calling them `frobnicate_wrapper_with_x` and `frobnicate_wrapper_with_x_and_y` is better. These new names feel correct and adequate. But at the same time it feels ridiculous because these names just point out that these are wrapping functions and are very shallow in the sense that they don't encapsulate anything. Rather they are more interface boilerplate than implementation.
- I need to change the arguments of `frobnicate()` in the next step. These have to be passed through all the wrappers. And actual function has seven arguments with complicated types, so the wrappers also have almost that many. I will have to change the signatures of three functions, which means changes in nine places (header, source, call-site), though the IDE helps with that. I learned that if a single change leads to changes in other places, something isn't encapsulated enough.

I thought that it might be better to call the function right away and just let each object give me the information that I need to call it, eliminating the wrappers. Then it would look like this:

```cpp
T result = frobnicate(a.get_x(), b.get_y(), z);
```

It feels a bit like the [*remove middle man* refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/removeMiddleMan.html). Is there some overarching principle or pattern that applies in a situation like this?

Comment: "is better but feels ridiculous." why does it feel ridiculous? Properly naming functions should not feel ridiculous

Comment: Unless holding those states is essential for these wrapper classes. I believe remove these wrapper classes is better. Especially when you need to change the signatures.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: The act of finding proper names isn't ridiculous. It is just that the proper names make apparent that the function is just a wrapper and _that_ feels ridiculous.

Comment: but it is a wrapper. When a name expresses what the function is, I would consider this as a good name

Comment: anyhow, my point is just that when you say "better but feels ridiculous" you need to explain what is ridiculous, because it is rather subjective

Comment: On the face of it, the wrappers strike me as unnecessary, and can be removed.    Try doing it with simple function overloading or (possibly) a single function that accepts its arguments in reverse order to what you have (e.g. `frobnicate(z, y, x)`) and give default values to the right-most arguments.     With a function that is named (literally) about tweaking, it seems appropriate to tweak its argument list.

Comment: Hard to say if wrappers make sense in your case. With your simplified example, there are indeed superfluous, but they might have sense in actual code. Wrappers might also allow to stop propagation of the changes (can be extra member of default value).

Comment: @Jarod42: The actual `frobnicate` function has many more parameters, the types are more complicated than `int`. But the pattern that each wrapper only adds one argument from one of its members is present in the actual code. I am now removing these wrappers and the code feels better already.

Comment: I meant, that `B` for example set 2/3 of the parameters. Passing `B` is probably better than passing several parameters (especially if the grouping make sense). but maybe the problem is that your original function has too many parameter and the above grouping is already missing. (on the other side only `A` handles only 1 parameter, so passing `A` or `x` directly is equivalent, so `x` would be simpler).